# Include py.typed file in wheel produced with nuitka

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, nuitka

I'm trying to build a wheel for a pyproject.toml based project using nuitka as described [here](https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#use-case-5-setuptools-wheels). I'd like to include a `py.typed` file in the final wheel. My repo structure looks like this

```
pyproject.toml
my_package/
    __init__.py
    my_file.py
    py.typed
```

I'm using the `[build-system]` section in pyproject.toml to specify that the wheel should be built with nuitka.

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "nuitka", "toml"]
build-backend = "nuitka.distutils.Build"
```

Under the nuitka configuration section, I've tried various combinations of `include-package-data` and `include-data-files`. The below appears to be most similar to the recommended setuptools pattern for including `py.typed` files.

```
[nuitka]
disable-ccache = true
include-package-data = "my_package=py.typed"
```

However, none of the settings I've tried result in a `py.typed`  file being included in the final wheel. How can I include this file?

Comment: Have you tried using *setuptools* `Manifest.in` to instruct `py.typed` files to be included? At least that is what I would try first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some [discussion](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/2219) with the maintainer of Nuitka on github, this was easier than expected. Nuitka defers to setuptools for the actual construction of the wheel so including a section like this will include the `py.typed` file in the resulting wheel.

```ini
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
my_package = ['py.typed']
```